# How to take a screenshot of ongoing video during a call in QuickBlox

Tags: ios, swift, quickblox

I would like to take a screenshot of ongoing `VideoCaptureView` during a call in iOS Swift. I used **QuickBlox**.

I have used below code that return black image

```
public extension UIView {

    public func snapshotImage() -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, isOpaque,0)
        drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)
        let snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return snapshotImage
    }

    public func snapshotView() -> UIView? {
        if let snapshotImage = snapshotImage() {
            return UIImageView(image: snapshotImage)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

let snapshot = view.snapshotView()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
fileprivate func captureUIImageFromUIView(_ view:UIView?) -> UIImage {

        guard (view != nil) else{

            // if the view is nil (it's happened to me) return an alternative image
            let errorImage = UIImage(named: "Logo.png")
            return errorImage!
        }

        // if the view is all good then convert the image inside the view to a uiimage
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {

            let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: view!.bounds.size)
            let capturedImage = renderer.image {
                (ctx) in
                view!.drawHierarchy(in: view!.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
            }
            return capturedImage

        } else {

            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions((view!.bounds.size), view!.isOpaque, 0.0)
            view!.drawHierarchy(in: view!.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)
            let capturedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            return capturedImage!
        }
    }
```

Call

```
let pdfImage = self.captureUIImageFromUIView(self.containerView)
```

//
//  ViewController.swift
//  GooglePlace-AutoComplete
//
//  Created by infos on 7/10/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 infos. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import GooglePlaces
import SwiftyJSON
import Alamofire

enum Location {
    case startLocation
    case destinationLocation
}

class ViewController: UIViewController , GMSMapViewDelegate ,  CLLocationManagerDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var googleMaps: GMSMapView!
@IBOutlet weak var startLocation: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var destinationLocation: UITextField!


var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var locationSelected = Location.startLocation
var polyline = GMSPolyline()
var locationStart = CLLocation()
var locationEnd = CLLocation()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyC55Dq1qPH7EM_uiAVf-8QuxJtf2W1viQs")
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyC55Dq1qPH7EM_uiAVf-8QuxJtf2W1viQs")


    // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 13.082680,
                                          longitude: 80.270718,
                                          zoom: 10.0,
                                          bearing: 30,
                                          viewingAngle: 40)
    //Setting the googleView
    googleMaps.camera = camera
    googleMaps.delegate = self
    googleMaps.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    googleMaps.settings.myLocationButton = true
    googleMaps.settings.compassButton = true
    googleMaps.settings.zoomGestures = true
    googleMaps.animate(to: camera)
    self.view.addSubview(googleMaps)

    //Setting the start and end location
    let origin = "\(13.082680),\(80.270718)"
    let destination = "\(15.912900),\(79.739987)"


    let url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(origin)&destination=\(destination)&mode=driving"

    //Rrequesting Alamofire and SwiftyJSON
    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in
        print(response.request as Any)  // original URL request
        print(response.response as Any) // HTTP URL response
        print(response.data as Any)     // server data
        print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

        do {
            let json = try JSON(data: response.data!)
            let routes = json["routes"].arrayValue

            for route in routes
            {
                let routeOverviewPolyline = route["overview_polyline"].dictionary
                let points = routeOverviewPolyline?["points"]?.stringValue
                let path = GMSPath.init(fromEncodedPath: points!)
                let polyline = GMSPolyline.init(path: path)
                polyline.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
                polyline.strokeWidth = 2
                polyline.map = self.googleMaps
            }
        }
        catch {

        }

    }


    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 28.524555, longitude: 77.275111)
    marker.title = "Mobiloitte"
    marker.snippet = "India"
    marker.map = googleMaps

    //28.643091, 77.218280
    let marker1 = GMSMarker()
    marker1.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 28.643091, longitude: 77.218280)
    marker1.title = "NewDelhi"
    marker1.snippet = "India"
    marker1.map = googleMaps
}

// MARK: function for create a marker pin on map
func createMarker(titleMarker: String, iconMarker: UIImage, latitude: CLLocationDegrees, longitude: CLLocationDegrees) {
    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
    marker.isDraggable=true
    marker.title = titleMarker
    marker.icon = iconMarker
    marker.map = googleMaps
}

//MARK: - Location Manager delegates

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print("Error to get location : \(error)")
}



func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let location = locations.last

    //  let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: (location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (location?.coordinate.longitude)!, zoom: 17.0)

    let locationMobi = CLLocation(latitude: 28.524555, longitude: 77.275111)


    drawPath(startLocation: location!, endLocation: locationMobi)

    //self.googleMaps?.animate(to: camera)
    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

}

// MARK: - GMSMapViewDelegate

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, idleAt position: GMSCameraPosition) {
    googleMaps.isMyLocationEnabled = true
}

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, willMove gesture: Bool) {
    googleMaps.isMyLocationEnabled = true

    if (gesture) {
        mapView.selectedMarker = nil
    }
}

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
    googleMaps.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    return false
}

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    print("COORDINATE \(coordinate)") // when you tapped coordinate
}

func didTapMyLocationButton(for mapView: GMSMapView) -> Bool {
    googleMaps.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    googleMaps.selectedMarker = nil
    return false
}

//MARK: - Marker Delegate

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didDrag marker: GMSMarker) {


}

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didBeginDragging marker: GMSMarker) {


}

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didEndDragging marker: GMSMarker) {
    self.googleMaps.reloadInputViews()

    //self.polyline.map = nil;
    print("marker dragged to location: \(marker.position.latitude),\(marker.position.longitude)")
    let locationMobi = CLLocation(latitude: marker.position.latitude, longitude: marker.position.longitude)
    self.drawPath(startLocation: locationMobi, endLocation: locationEnd)

}



//MARK: - this is function for create direction path, from start location to desination location

func drawPath(startLocation: CLLocation, endLocation: CLLocation)
{
    let origin = "\(startLocation.coordinate.latitude),\(startLocation.coordinate.longitude)"
    let destination = "\(endLocation.coordinate.latitude),\(endLocation.coordinate.longitude)"

    self.polyline.map = nil
    //self.googleMaps.clear()

    let url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(origin)&destination=\(destination)&mode=driving"

    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in

        print(response.request as Any)  // original URL request
        print(response.response as Any) // HTTP URL response
        print(response.data as Any)     // server data
        print(response.result as Any)   // result of response serialization

        do {
            let json = try JSON(data: response.data!)
            let routes = json["routes"].arrayValue

            // print route using Polyline
            for route in routes
            {
                let routeOverviewPolyline = route["overview_polyline"].dictionary
                let points = routeOverviewPolyline?["points"]?.stringValue
                let path = GMSPath.init(fromEncodedPath: points!)
                self.polyline = GMSPolyline.init(path: path)
                self.polyline.strokeWidth = 2
                self.polyline.strokeColor = UIColor.red
                self.polyline.map = self.googleMaps
            }
        } catch {

        }

    }
}

// MARK: when start location tap, this will open the search location
@IBAction func openStartLocation(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let autoCompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
    autoCompleteController.delegate = self

    // selected location
    locationSelected = .startLocation

    // Change text color
    UISearchBar.appearance().setTextColor(color: UIColor.black)
    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    self.present(autoCompleteController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// MARK: when destination location tap, this will open the search location
@IBAction func openDestinationLocation(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let autoCompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
    autoCompleteController.delegate = self

    // selected location
    locationSelected = .destinationLocation

    // Change text color
    UISearchBar.appearance().setTextColor(color: UIColor.black)
    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    self.present(autoCompleteController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


// MARK: SHOW DIRECTION WITH BUTTON
@IBAction func showDirection(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // when button direction tapped, must call drawpath func
    self.drawPath(startLocation: locationStart, endLocation: locationEnd)
}
```

}

// MARK: - GMS Auto Complete Delegate, for autocomplete search location
extension ViewController: GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate {

```
func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didFailAutocompleteWithError error: Error) {
    print("Error \(error)")
}

func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {

    // Change map location
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: place.coordinate.latitude, longitude: place.coordinate.longitude, zoom: 16.0
    )

    // set coordinate to text
    if locationSelected == .startLocation {
        if (self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude) != nil {
            startLocation.text = "\(place.coordinate.latitude), \(place.coordinate.longitude)"
            locationStart = CLLocation(latitude: place.coordinate.latitude, longitude: place.coordinate.longitude)
            createMarker(titleMarker: "Location Start", iconMarker: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "images"), latitude: place.coordinate.latitude, longitude: place.coordinate.longitude)
        }else {
            // handle the error by declaring default value
        }

    } else {
        if (self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude) != nil {
            destinationLocation.text = "\(place.coordinate.latitude), \(place.coordinate.longitude)"
            locationEnd = CLLocation(latitude: place.coordinate.latitude, longitude: place.coordinate.longitude)
            createMarker(titleMarker: "Location End", iconMarker: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "images"), latitude: place.coordinate.latitude, longitude: place.coordinate.longitude)
        }else {
            // handle the error by declaring default value
        }

    }


    self.googleMaps.camera = camera
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func wasCancelled(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func didRequestAutocompletePredictions(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
}

func didUpdateAutocompletePredictions(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
}
```

}
public func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
{
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
public extension UISearchBar {

```
public func setTextColor(color: UIColor) {
    let svs = subviews.flatMap { $0.subviews }
    guard let tf = (svs.filter { $0 is UITextField }).first as? UITextField else { return }
    tf.textColor = color
}
```

}

Comment: It shows black image for cameraview. Thanks for the answer

Comment: I have used quickblox for video chat and I want to give user a functionality to take snapshot of current live camera view of video chat.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is working code to take a screenshot of ongoing video during a call in QuickBlox**

```
@IBOutlet weak var stackView: UIStackView!

let stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    QBRTCClient.initializeRTC()
    QBRTCClient.instance().add(self)

    cofigureVideo()
}

func cofigureVideo() {

    QBRTCConfig.mediaStreamConfiguration().videoCodec = .H264
    QBRTCConfig.setAnswerTimeInterval(30)
    QBRTCConfig.setStatsReportTimeInterval(5)

    let videoFormat = QBRTCVideoFormat.init()
    videoFormat.frameRate = 30
    videoFormat.pixelFormat = .format420f
    videoFormat.width = 640
    videoFormat.height = 480

    self.videoCapture = QBRTCCameraCapture.init(videoFormat: videoFormat, position: .front)

    self.videoCapture.previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill

    self.videoCapture.startSession {

        self.stillImageOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey:AVVideoCodecJPEG]
        if self.videoCapture.captureSession.canAddOutput(self.stillImageOutput) {
            self.videoCapture.captureSession.addOutput(self.stillImageOutput)
        }

        let localView = LocalVideoView.init(withPreviewLayer:self.videoCapture.previewLayer)
        self.stackView.addArrangedSubview(localView)
    }
}
```

**Take photo Button Click**

```
@IBAction func TakePhotoTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput.connection(with: AVMediaType.video) {
        stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection) {
            (imageDataSampleBuffer, error) -> Void in
            let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(imageDataSampleBuffer!)

            if let image = UIImage(data: imageData!){
                // Your image is Here
            }
        }
    }
}
```